# Accessing BeagleBone from the Internet(not from browser)

Tags: webserver, embedded-linux, web-controls, beagleboard, asp.net-webcontrol

I wanted to get a head start on how I can  control my beaglebone Black from the internet preferably I will have android app there on the other part!

I have gone through a lot of tutorials but all they do is access it using the browser and I want to access it through my Android phone's app that may be a TCP/IP app.

So wanted to know whether I should use the Webserver or not if yes which? Tornado, node.js and some headstart on how to do it step by step

Comment: Are you familiar with sockets programming?  If so, you don't need to use a web server.  Just listen on a port on the beaglebone and connect to it from an app.  Of course, the security and routing, etc. must be figured out.

Comment: Yes completely I have written TCP/IP sockets apps in Visual C# and as well as Java in eclipse for Android BUT the problem there arises of PORT FORWARDING which I was never able to resolve given my APN.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do use port forwarding.  Perhaps you do.  Can you ping your BeagleBone from another system on the net (outside of your subnet)?  You can write a simple app that listens on a non-privileged port and see if a remote system can connect() to it.